# VB.NET - Convert an anonymous delegate to normal delegate or method

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have an anonymous delegate here declared as :

```
Private AO As System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation
```

And used as :

```
  AO.Post(Sub(x) Count(DirectCast(x, intInteger)), integerX)
```

I just got the code online, I want to learn it but first I want to see the whole picture of the method, they said that anonymous delegates are somewhat shortcuts of delegates + subs.

Is it like Delegate sub + private delagate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, for future reference, here it is :

```
Private AO As System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation

AO.Post(New Threading.SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf HandleInteger),integerX)

Sub HandleInteger(ByVal objData_ As Object)
      Dim intData As Integer = DirectCast(objData_, Integer)
      Count(intData)
End Sub
```